# Why possible to define multiple mutable references if don't use them?

Tags: rust

To prevent data conflict, a variable cannot have its multiple mutable references at the same time but why we can just define unsafe references and get a passed compile, if we don't use them at all?

```
fn tut(){
    let mut s = String::from("hello");
    let s1 = &mut s;
    let s2 = &mut s;
    let s3 = &mut s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have three mutable references at once. From https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html:

> Note that a reference’s scope starts from where it is introduced and continues through the last time that reference is used.

`s2` is not in the same scope as `s1`, because `s1` is never used again after `s2` is defined. Likewise, `s2` is never used after `s3` is defined.

This is similar to the example shown in the link above:

```
let mut s = String::from("hello");

let r1 = &s; // no problem
let r2 = &s; // no problem
println!("{} and {}", r1, r2);
// variables r1 and r2 will not be used after this point

let r3 = &mut s; // no problem
println!("{}", r3);
```

`r3` is allowed because even though two immutable references were defined, neither `r1` nor `r2` is used again after `r3` is defined, so they are no longer in scope to prevent `r3` from being defined.